# Installing RPM packages with circular dependency

Tags: rhel, rpm

I'm trying to follow [an article to enable smart card login](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Smart_Cards/enabling-smart-card-login.html) on my RHEL 6.6 desktop. When I attempt to install coolkey-1.1.0, it says ccid and pcsc-lite is needed.

- When attempt to install ccid-1.3.9.7, it says pcsc-lite is needed.
- When I attempt to install pcsc-lite-1.5.2, it says pcsc-ifd-handler is required.
- When I search Google to see what rpm I need to get pcsc-ifd-handler, it looks like pcsc-ifd-handler is [included in the ccid or pcsc-lite-openct package](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=144738).

I already tried to install ccid and it needed pcsc-lite, so then I tried to install pcsc-lite-openct-0.6.19 and it also says it needs pcsc-lite.

So I'm kind of stuck in a cycle where the package that has pcsc-ifd-handler is dependent on pcsc-lite being installed, but pcsc-lite can't install until the package that contains pcsc-ifd-handler is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Circular dependencies are usually resolved by picking one of the RPM's in question and just doing a `--nodeps --force` on the install then proceeding onto the other one.

I've read elsewhere that you can just give both files to `rpm` at the same time and that will work around it. Never done that myself, though.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I installed the pcsc-lite package with --force --nodeps and now I am able to install the other rpms.

Comment: Just verified that for circular dependencies you can give both to the `rpm` command at the same time and have it installed

Comment: You could have simply installed those packages via `yum`, and it would have automatically resolved those dependencies between the packages. (that is, if ccid provides pcsc-ifd-handler). `yum` would also provide the benefit of pulling additional dependencies from the repositories, if there would be any.

Comment: `yum` could be a possibility, but I was trying to answer the question as directly as I could. It's possible they have particular RPM's that they're wanting to install, for instance. Plus `yum` implies they have access to the repo's in question. If this is a rhel machine without an active entitlement manually installing the RPM's is pretty much the only feasible alternative. I didn't want to get into all that. If I had it to write over again I'd do what Ashwin suggested since that seems safer and even more direct. I just didn't know `rpm` worked like that.

Comment: A million thanks.  I am working on an air-gapped RHEL 7.9 and got into a circular dependency between git and perl-Git.  I was able to install perl-Git with --nodeps --force and then git with the normal -i switch.  I've been doing rpm installs.  Not fun but they will work with a lot of persistence and resourcefulness.

Answer (score 4):

Give all the RPMs in a single line:

```
rpm -ivh [RPM 1] [RPM 2] [RPM 3] .....
```

In your case it would be:

```
rpm -ivh coolkey-1.1.0 ccid-1.3.9.7 pcsc-lite-1.5.2
```